Relationship problem with SQLAlchemy and SQLite in Python
I created a db in SQLite and added tables with SQLAlchemy.
DB_URL = "sqlite:///wimp.sqlite3"

engine = create_engine(DB_URL, echo=True)

Session = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
session = Session()

Base = declarative_base()

Models for SQLAlchemy:
from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    Integer,
    String,
    ForeignKey
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from connection.connection_db import Base, session


class Container(Base):
    __tablename__ = "container"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(100), nullable=False, index=True)
    type = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    port = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    server_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("server.id"))
    sites = relationship("Site")


class Server(Base):
    __tablename__ = "server"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ip = Column(Integer, nullable=False, index=True)
    name = Column(String(100), nullable=False, index=True)
    cpu = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    ram = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    containers = relationship("Container")


class Site(Base):
    __tablename__ = "site"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ip = Column(Integer, nullable=False, index=True)
    domain = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    url = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    tls_certificate = Column(String(500), nullable=False)
    container_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("container.id"))

I also added rows from two of my Json and CSV files to the database.
Now the id, name, type,port columns of the Container table and the ip domain url, tls_certificate columns of the Site table, the id, ip, name, cpu, ram columns of the Server table are populated.
While the server_id and container_id columns are not populated.
The problem is that now I don't know how to add the relationship.
Can someone explain to me how to do this in an example?
